# Confusion regarding steps in bipartite matching proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can someone please explain how it follows that $|N(S)|x \geq |S|x$? What I'm asking is why is it necessary to use the value of x to derive the inequality?

**Theorem 5.2.7.** Let G be a bipartite graph with vertex partition L, R where $|L| \leq |R|$. If G is degree-constrained, then there is a matching that covers L.

Proof.

The proof is by contradiction. Suppose that G is degree constrained but that
there is no matching that covers L. By Theorem 5.2.5, this means that there must
be a bottleneck $S \subseteq L$.
Let x be a value such that $deg(l) \geq x \geq deg(r)$ for every $l \epsilon L$ and $r \epsilon R$.
Since every edge incident to a node in S is incident to a node in N(S), we know
that
\begin{aligned}
|N(S)|x \geq |S|x
\end{aligned}
and thus that
\begin{aligned}
|N(S)| \geq  |S|
\end{aligned}
This means that S is not a bottleneck, which is a contradiction. Hence G has a
matching that covers L.

EDIT:

For clarification (hopefully), this theorem builds on the definition of a bottleneck where:

\begin{aligned}
G \ is \ the \ bipartite \ graph \ (V,E)
\end{aligned}

So the graph is partitioned in to L and R, where:

\begin{aligned}
S \subseteq L
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
N(S) = \{r \ | \ \{s,r\} \ \epsilon \ E \ for \ some \ s \ \epsilon \ S \}  
\end{aligned}

Meaning that N(S) is a neighbor of some vertex in s, and:

\begin{aligned}
|S| \geq |N(S)|
\end{aligned}

implies that a bottleneck exists.

Comment: What is N(S) here?

Comment: $N(S)$ is the neighborhood of $S$.

Comment: I don't get it at all...maybe we use different definitions of 'matching', 'degree constrained' or 'covers'.  In particular, I don't see why $x$ must exist.  Can you tell me the problem with this reasoning : suppose $|L| > |R|$ and there is a matching $M$ (a set of edges) that covers $L$.  Then $|M| = |L| > |R|$, so there must be a vertex $r \in R$ that is used in at least two edges of $M$ - so $M$ is not a matching.

Comment: @manuellafond Good catch. I accidentally flipped the inequality when I was re-writing the proof in Latex. Sorry, first time using latex so I was more focused on syntax than semantics. I meant to say $ |L| \leq |R| $

Comment: OK good !  I still can't answer this question though and I'm wondering.  It all depends on the existence of $x$, which is somehow assumed.  Can you define 'degree-constrained' ?

Comment: degree constrained for a bipartite graph $G$ means that every for all $l \ \epsilon \ L$ and $r \ \epsilon \ R$ the $deg(l) \geq deg(r)$. This means that every vertex in the partition $R$ is incident to a greater than or equal number of edges than any member of $L$. The existence of x can be assumed because we know that for the smallest deg(l) and the largest deg(r), $deg(l) \geq deg(r)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of subtle but everything is in 'Since every edge incident to a node in $S$ is incident to a node in $N(S)$'.

Here's how you can see this.
Let $e(S)$ and $e(N(S))$ respectively denote the number of edges incident to some vertex of $S$ and $N(S)$.

Then, $e(N(S)) \geq e(S)$, since every edge counted in $e(S)$ has to be counted in $e(N(S))$ (as every edge with an endpoint in $S$ has an its other endpoint in $N(S)$.

We have $|S|x \leq e(S)$ since $x \leq deg(l)$ for all $l \in S$.

And we have $|N(S)|x \geq e(N(S))$ since $x \geq deg(r)$ for all $r \in N(S)$.

Putting all this together in the correct order, you get the inequality chain

$|S|x \leq e(S) \leq e(N(S)) \leq |N(S)|x$.

Comment: Thank you. That really clarifies it for me!